# IOS7 Notification sync

Tags: notifications, ios7

iOS7 now supports Notification Sync that sync notifications across all ios devices. (http://www.cultofmac.com/230901/ios-7-has-notifications-sync-call-blocking-and-will-make-the-iphone-theft-rate-plummet-wwdc-2013/)

But I can't find any API or documentation describing the way to use it when building an app. Can this feature be used by only a few pre-defined apps such as iMessagse, Gmail, etc?